# [heroku CI][cypress] Cannot integration Cypress with Heroko CI

Tags: cypress, heroku-ci

I am unable to run cypress UAT tests on heroku-18 stack. Cypress requires Xvfb, however xvfd build-pack is not supports on heroku stack.
Does anyone know when this will be avaliable ? Or is there any other way to get this working.

Thanks